# When Does SQL Server Choose to Recompile Stored Procedure Execution Plans Automatically?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am working through the following articles:

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Parameter+Sniffing/98481/

https://kohera.be/blog/sql-server/tackle-parameter-sniffing-in-sql-server-2017-and-azure-sql-database/

In both examples, if I execute the stored proc with the same parameter values more than 3 times, SQL Server (2017) seems to switch to the more correct execution plan automatically.

For example:

```
CREATE PROECEDURE Sales 
    @OrderDate datetime
AS
    SELECT 
         sod.SalesOrderID,sod.OrderQty,sod.UnitPrice,soh.OrderDate 
    FROM
         sales.salesorderdetail sod
    INNER JOIN
         sales.salesorderheader soh
    ON
         sod.SalesOrderID = soh.SalesOrderID
    WHERE 
         soh.OrderDate < @OrderDate
    ORDER BY 
         sod.UnitPrice
    GO

EXEC Sales '20110730'
EXEC Sales '20140730'
```

If I run the top exec twice then SQL chooses Execution plan A.
If I then run the second exec, it uses Execution plan A a few times. But after 3 executions it changes to Execution plan B.
If I go back and run the first query a few times it eventually switches back to A.
Two questions. Please answer both:

1. How does SQL decide when to stop using the cached plan and create a new one?
2. Since SQL seems to automatically switch query plans after enough executions with different parameters, doesn't this make any "bad parameter sniffing" issues redundant, since SQL should correct itself after a few executions?

Please note the database in question has Parameter Sniffing switched on:
[image]